# Writing a jasmine test spec to a javascript closure function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, closures, jasmine, anonymous-function

I have a Javascript function in a view which is enclosed in a closure. The closure returns a function of the same name and also has some helpers. This is the structure of the method.

```
this.myMethod = (function () {

    function helperMethod(){
        ....
        return true;
    }
    return function myMethod(args){
        helperMethod();
        manipulate();
    }
}
```

My question is how do I write a Jasmine Unit Test spec to this method. How can I invoke this method ?

Using the default way of methods does not work in this case as it is anonymous.

```
var view = new myView();

    view.myMethod();

    expect ( true ).toBeTruthy();
```

Please help in this regard. I am a beginner to Jasmine Framework.

Comment: More specifically, I want to test the method 'helperMethod', which is not invoked directly by the closure function but passed to an external routine and invoked conditionally from the external method. It is passed as argument from the closure function. Hence I am unable to test the inner function because I will mock the external function when testing the closure function ( here, myMethod ).

Answer (score 1):

By closing over the `helperMethod` function, you've made it inaccessible to your specs so you won't be able to test it directly. You can either test it indirectly by going through the existing public interface (`myMethod`) or by extracting the `helperMethod` from the closure in some way to make it accessible publicly, this could be as a prototype method on the view, or just on `this`, or on a completely different helpery object altogether.